# HTML error 405 despite IIS Request Filtering "Allow unlisted verbs"

Tags: html, asp.net, iis

So, I've put together a simple ASP.NET site; I have multiple cases where I've tied Button PostBackURL to a server-side .htm file, with no problem.   Now, I've added a large number of other .htm files that were batch-converted from Word .doc files, but accessing any of them in the same manner provokes a "405" error (Bad HTML verb).   I see no evidence anywhere (IIS log) saying which specific verb is the culprit.  I've been cranking the Google machine heavily, but don't see anything that will truly show me how to diagnose this.  Hmm?

added GET, HEAD, POST, TRACE verbs to IIS Request Filtering; checked Allow unlisted verbs - True.
The .htm files that provoke the error CAN be opened successfully in Chrome, on the same server machine.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing Read more from FRT.

Comment: @Lex Li - Thanks for that link.   I've actually reworked my dynamic page creation to use HyperLink objects rather than LinkButtons, after looking at some other recommendations.  It's now working! :)

Comment: Glad you solved it. I have encountered the same 405 error. Renaming the page to .aspx worked for me.